# Python: deleting a row from Bigtable by its row-key

Tags: python, bigtable

this is simple: I want to delete a row, by its row-key, from Bigtable, using Python. The documentation for this is woefully lacking. How is this done?

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

```
from google.cloud import bigtable

PROJECT_ID = ####
INSTANCE_NAME = ####
TABLE_NAME = ####


def delete_row(row_key):
    client = bigtable.Client(project=PROJECT_ID, admin=True)
    instance = client.instance(INSTANCE_NAME)
    table_instance = instance.table(TABLE_NAME)
 
    row = table_instance.row(row_key)
    row.delete()
    row.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    delete_row("my-row-key-to-delete")
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that deleting the row by key is documented here: https://googleapis.dev/python/bigtable/latest/row.html#google.cloud.bigtable.row.ConditionalRow.delete